# Mysql subquery not displaying rows

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT a.vardas, a.pavarde FROM `y6fdt_igym_abonementai` AS a 
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT max(galiojaiki) gal, id, abonementas FROm y6fdt_igym_sutartys
) c
on c.abonementas = a.id
```

Why I see only a.vardas and a.pavarde columns as result. But not id, abonementas from subquery ?

Comment: Just for your info. Did you check the result of the subquery? Because that "max" without a "group by" on the other fields can give you another result as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to see those columns, you have to add them to the main `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT a.vardas, a.pavarde, c.gal, c.id, c.abonementas
FROM `y6fdt_igym_abonementai` AS a 
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT max(galiojaiki) gal, id, abonementas FROm y6fdt_igym_sutartys
) c
on c.abonementas = a.id
```

Note that the `id` and `abonementas` columns in the subquery will not be from row with `max(galiojaiki)`. It will just take them from some random row in the table. If you want those specific values, you need to use:

```
SELECT a.vardas, a.pavarde, c.gal, c.id, c.abonementas
FROM `y6fdt_igym_abonementai` AS a 
FROM y6fdt_igym_sutartys AS c ON c.abonementas = a.id
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT max(galiojaiki) AS maxgal 
    FROm y6fdt_igym_sutartys
) d on c.galiojaiki = d.maxgal
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
SELECT a.vardas, a.pavarde FROM `y6fdt_igym_abonementai` AS a 
 ...
SELECT max(galiojaiki) gal, id, abonementas FROm y6fdt_igym_sutartys
```

to

```
SELECT a.vardas, a.pavarde FROM `y6fdt_igym_abonementai` a 
...

SELECT max(c.galiojaiki) c.gal, c.id, c.abonementas FROm y6fdt_igym_sutartys c
```